# How i resolve comunication problem opcua library with pyinstaller?

Tags: sockets, pyinstaller, opc-ua

i have problem with pyinstaller i use library opcua for comunication, with normal run in pycharm everything works correctly, after create .exe with pyinstaller after few second or minute the comunication stops.

```
from opcua import Client
from opcua.crypto import security_policies
from opcua.ua import MessageSecurityMode
from opcua import ua

def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.set_security(policy=security_policies.SecurityPolicyBasic256Sha256,
                                     certificate_path=self.root_path+CERT_RELATIVE_PATH,
                                     private_key_path=self.root_path+PRIVATE_KEY_RELATIVE_PATH,
                                     mode=MessageSecurityMode.SignAndEncrypt
                                     )
            self.client.application_uri = "urn:script:opcua"

            # self.client.secure_channel_timeout = 10000
            self.client.session_timeout = 60000

            self.client.connect()
            self.root_node = self.client.get_root_node()
            self.call_method('ns=2;s=/Methods/GiveUserAccess', 'OpcUaClient', 'GudWrite')
            return True
        except Exception:
            self.main_log.info('unable to connect to nc: {}'.format(traceback.format_exc()))
            raise custom_exceptions.UnableToConnect()

    def get_battery_100(self):
        return self.client.get_node('ns=2;s=/NC/_N_NC_GD2_ACX/DG_BATTERY_TIME').get_value()
```

This is the error after some data exchange:

```
WARNING:opcua.uaprotocol:Received an error: MessageAbort(error:StatusCode(BadSecurityChecksFailed), reason:None)
CRITICAL:opcua.client.ua_client.Socket:Received an error: MessageAbort(error:StatusCode(BadSecurityChecksFailed), reason:None)
ERROR:opcua.client.ua_client.Socket:Protocol Error
..
  File "opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 101, in _run
  File "opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 121, in _receive
  File "opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 129, in _call_callback
opcua.ua.uaerrors._base.UaError: No future object found for request: 0, callbacks in list are dict_keys([8612, 8613])
..
..
..
  File "opcua\common\node.py", line 155, in get_value
  File "opcua\common\node.py", line 164, in get_data_value
  File "opcua\common\node.py", line 275, in get_attribute
  File "opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 347, in read
  File "opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 83, in send_request
  File "concurrent\futures_base.py", line 443, in result
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
```

do you know if there is any modification to make to make it work in pyinstaller for comunication0?

(class with this module is call with a thread)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved. when i created the .exe file with pyinstaller i copied the .der and .pem certificates (all in the same pc) but if i delete them and with python I recreate them automatically, the program works correctly, instead with old certificates, the connection is unstable.

Answer (score 0):

BadSecurityChecksFailed related to security, are you shure you are destribute the correct certificates? Or if you are using your client on another device, are you matching the correct hostname/ipaddress in the certificates?